# problem with conditions in case when in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I wanted to add a case when WPIS_ where if frm_code is one of the codes mentioned then we ASSIGNY W if not then B. I get "Syntax error" what I do wrong
Rest code is working

```
PROC SQL;     
create table PolisyEnd as 
    select distinct       
    t1.data_danych as data_danych 
     ,t4.spr_NRB as NRB
     ,intnx('month',datepart(t1.PRP_END_DATE),0,'b') format=yymmd7. as POLICY_VINTAGE,
case
    when datepart(t1.PRP_END_DATE) IS NOT NULL and datepart(t1.PRP_END_DATE) - &gv_date_dly. < 0 THEN 'W' 
    when datepart(t1.PRP_END_DATE) IS NOT NULL and datepart(t1.PRP_END_DATE) - &gv_date_dly. > 0 THEN 'A' 
    when datepart(t1.PRP_END_DATE) IS NULL THEN 'NO INFO' 

    end as POLISA_INFORMACJA
case
    when t5.frm_code = 'C11' then 'W'
    and t5.frm_code = 'A11' then 'W'
    and t5.frm_code ='C30' then 'W'
    and t5.frm_code 'ZH1' then 'W'
    else 'B'
    end as WPIS_
from 
    cmz.WMDTZDP_BH t1
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly there? datepart(t1.PRP_END_DATE) - &gv_date_dl

Comment: This is ok i have error here : case
    when t5.frm_code = 'C11' then 'W'

Comment: Missing comma after `POLISA_INFORMACJA`, voting to close as typo

Comment: nope, its not help @HoneyBadger

Comment: You can remove the "datepart(t1.PRP_END_DATE) IS NOT NULL" parts from the case expression. (NULL values won't pass the following condition anyway.) And have a pure ELSE clause for NO INFO. What about `= 0`?

Comment: You could reduce a lof of cases, as example writing case when t5.frm_code in ('C11', 'A11', 'C30', ZH1') then 'W' else 'B' end. Furthermore, if you don't want to reduce them, you have at least to replace your "and" by "when" in these lines.

Comment: What database do you use ? SQLServer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @HoneyBadger noted, there should be a comma after the first `case` statement.

Also there is 'and' instead of 'when' 3 times in the second `case` statement.

It looks like '=' is missing in  `t5.frm_code 'ZH1' then 'W'`.

There must also be a semi-colon at the very end.

Comment: There should be commas **before** both CASE clauses.